# python beautifulsoup: replace links with url in string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

In a string containing HTML I have several links that I want to replace with the pure href value:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
a = "<a href='www.google.com'>foo</a> some text <a href='www.bing.com'>bar</a> some <br> text'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

tags = soup.find_all()
for tag in tags:
  if tag.has_attr('href'):
    html = html.replace(str(tag), tag['href'])
```

Unfortunatly this creates some issues:

- the  tags in the html use single quotes `'`, but beautifulsoup will create with `str(tag)` an tag with `"` quotes (`<a href="www.google.com">foo</a>`). So `replace()` will not find the match.
- `<br>` get identified as `<br/>`. Again `replace()` will not find the match.

So it seems using python's `replace()` method will not give reliable results.

Is there a way to use beautifulsoup's methods to replace a tag with a string?

#### edit:

Added value for str(tag) = `<a href="www.google.com">foo</a>`

Comment: ‘ and “ are interchangeable (as long as you end the string with the same character) and both represent strings.

Comment: The issue is with quotes inside the string.

Comment: For me, BS just prints `'href'` and not `"href"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Relevant part of the docs: [Modifying the tree](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#modifying-the-tree)

```
html="""
<html><head></head>
<body>
<a href="www.google.com">foo</a> some text 
<a href="www.bing.com">bar</a> some <br> text
</body></html>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for a_tag in soup.find_all('a'):
    a_tag.string = a_tag.get('href')
print(soup)
```

output

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
<a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a> some text 
<a href="www.bing.com">www.bing.com</a> some <br/> text
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thats a good approach. It solved my issue. I only had to use `soup.text` in the end and get the required result.